# Vim plugin like SublimeREPL

Tags: plugin-system

I'm new to Vim editor.

I used Sublime Text before using Vim. In Sublime Text, there was a plugin named [SublimeREPL](https://github.com/wuub/SublimeREPL), which is optimized for using REPL such as `irb`, `python`, and `scala`. The plugin highlighted the code I type and provide a simple code completion like this.

[image]

Is there any plugin similar to this in Vim?

Comment: I'm putting this in a comment since I'm not sure it'll work well or at all with languages outside of the Lisp family, but [Slimv](https://bitbucket.org/kovisoft/slimv) provides a REPL and other quick expression evaluation tools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might find [Shougo's VimShell](https://github.com/Shougo/vimshell.vim) similar. It gives you a terminal session in a Vim buffer, which is quite neat!

However, in my experience, I've found it to be a little buggy. YMMV. Also, three days ago, development on it officially stopped.

I think it's fair to say that things like this have been on vimmers' wishlists for some time now. Unfortunately, I don't know that it'll ever happen. Vim's strength is that it's a terrific editor -- but the price for that is that Vim's buffers don't lend themselves too well to the sort of interaction a CLI needs. So we *can* run a terminal in a Vim buffer, but I don't know that it'll ever be quite right; it's not what Vim's designed to do.

Instead, I offer you two alternatives I use after experimenting with VimShell and finding it wasn't for me -- but they'll only work with Vim in a terminal, not something like gvim:

1. Using something to do terminal multiplexing, like tmux. Using this you can break a shell out at the side of your vim window, or have a shell in another tmux panel, or what have you. I use this every day, and seriously recommend getting into tmux as a part of your development environment.
2. CTRL-z is your friend. Really, the shell that you launched Vim from is only a key command away. CTRL-z will pause Vim, background it, and bring you back to your shell. You can launch your repl from there, and when you're done, the `fg` command will bring Vim back to the foreground. Experiment with it! It's really simple in practice. I use this every day also.

Hope that helps!